# How to read from a file or a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say you have a piece of code that accepts either a list or a file name, and must filter through each item of either one provided by applying the same criteria:

```python
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required = True)
group.add_argument('-n', '--name', help = 'single name', action = 'append')
group.add_argument('-N', '--names', help = 'text file of names')
args = parser.parse_args()

results = []

if args.name:
    # We are dealing with a list.
    for name in args.name:
        name = name.strip().lower()
        if name not in results and len(name) > 6: results.append(name)

else:
    # We are dealing with a file name.
    with open(args.names) as f:
        for name in f:
            name = name.strip().lower()
            if name not in results and len(name) > 6: results.append(name)
```

I'd like to remove as much redundancy as possible in the above code. I tried creating the following function for `strip` and `lower`, but it didn't remove much repeat code:

```python
def getFilteredName(name):
    return name.strip().lower()
```

Is there any way to iterate over both a list and a file in the same function? How should I go about reducing as much code as possible?

Comment: I think you are on the right track, why not put everything in the `def` from `name = ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate code that you can simplify: `list` and `file-objects` are both *iterables* - if you create a method that takes an `iterable` and returns the correct output you have less code duplication (DRY).

*Choice of datastructure:*

You do not want duplicate items, meaning `set()` or `dict()` are better suited to collect the data you want to parse - they eliminate duplicates *by design* which is faster then looking if an item is already `in` a list:

- if the order of names matter use

  - a `OrderedDict` from `collections` when on python 3.6 or less or
  - a normal `dict` for 3.7 or more (dicts gurantee input order)
  - more info: [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)
- if name order is not important, use a `set()`

Either one of the above choices removes duplicates for you.

```
import argparse
from collections import OrderedDict # use normal dict on 3.7+ it hasinput order

def get_names(args):
    """Takes an iterable and returns a list of all unique lower cased elements, that
    have at least length 6."""

    seen = OrderedDict() # or dict or set

    def add_names(iterable):
        """Takes care of adding the stuff to your return collection."""
        k = [n.strip().lower() for n in iterable] # do the strip().split()ing only once
        # using generator comp to update - use .add() for set()
        seen.update( ((n,None) for n in k if len(n)>6))

    if args.name:
        # We are dealing with a list:
        add_names(args.name)

    elif args.names:
        # We are dealing with a file name:
        with open(args.names) as f:
            add_names(f)

    # return as list    
    return list(seen)
```

---

Testcode:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required = True)
group.add_argument('-n', '--name', help = 'single name', action = 'append')
group.add_argument('-N', '--names', help = 'text file of names')
args = parser.parse_args()

results = get_names(args)

print(results)
```

Output for `-n Joh3333n -n Ji3333m -n joh3333n -n Bo3333b -n bo3333b -n jim`:

```
['joh3333n', 'ji3333m', 'bo3333b']
```

Input file:

```
with open("names.txt","w") as names:
    for n in ["a"*k for k in range(1,10)]:
        names.write( f"{n}\n")
```

Output for `-N names.txt`:

```
['aaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaaa']
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a nice solution. I would only tweak it very little to suit my code more, and edit ```add_names``` so that there is only one iteration of ```iterable``` (instead of iterating over ```iterable``` and then further iterating over ```k```) which ```strip```s, ```lower```s, checks ```len```, and adds to ```seen``` in one go.

Comment: @Hank if you do `{n.strip().lower() for w in iterable if len(n.strip()) > 6}` (using a set) it will strip() twice for every n - python is bad at optimizing list comps - that why I split it - but it is shorter code. It might matter if you feed it a file with a million names - it won't if you provide 5 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `list` and make the subclass a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers):

```
class F(list):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        pass
```

Then the conditional can decide what to iterate over

```
if args.name:
    # We are dealing with a list.
    thing = F(args.name)
else:
    # We are dealing with a file name.
    thing = open(args.names)
```

And the iteration code can be factored out.

```
results = []

with thing as f:
    for name in f:
        name = name.strip().lower()
        if name not in results and len(name) > 6: results.append(name)
```

---

Here is a similar solution that makes an `io.StringIO` object from either the file or the list then uses a *single* set of instructions to process them.

```
import io

if args.name:
    # We are dealing with a list.
    f = io.StringIO('\n'.join(args.name))
else:
    # We are dealing with a file name.
    with open(args.names) as fileobj:
        f = io.StringIO(fileobj.read())

results = []

for name in f:
    name = name.strip().lower()
    if name not in results and len(name) > 6: results.append(name)
```

If the file is huge and memory is scarce, this has the disadvantage of reading the entire file into memory.

Comment: The context manager doesn't add anything. Moving the loop into a function would be an improvement.

Comment: @cco `list`'s are not context managers - they do not have `__entry__` or `__exit__` methods; the subclass allows the list to be used with a `with` statement making that part of the code common between the two objects - which is what the OP desired, reducing code duplication. Without it, the code would throw an AttributeError for a list.  Did you try it without the subclass?  Indeed I tested it with that last bit in a function but not knowing how the OP's program is structured I just wanted to show a way to deal with the duplicate code.

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood the OP's problem/question.

Comment: This solution works, and is less code than the accepted answer, but seems like too hacky of a solution. Thank you for the creative perspective on it, though!

Comment: this is a "think outside the box" solution, dv wasn't mine but I'll compensate

Comment: Thnx, It was the first thing that came to mind - see edit for similar approach.

Comment: Using `with` doesn't reduce duplicated code, it merely makes the duplicated code *exactly* the same in both cases. Moving the body of your `with` to a function will reduce duplication.

Comment: @cco - You are missing the point. I'm not implying that using `with` would reduce duplicated code.  It is preferable to use `with` when working with a file. Making a list that is also a context manager allows *me* to use the iteration code, including the `with` statement, for either iterable.